# wrong calculation result in Xcode

Tags: casting, floating-point-precision

I have this calculation:

```
float tempd = 2451545 + 0.0009 + (77.048759/360) + 4682;
NSLog(@"tempd : %f", tempd);
```

The result using Xcode is : 2456227.250000
But it should be : 2456227.21492

Do you guys have any idea what I'm doing wrong? 
I cant seem to figure it out.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Oh look, it's time for the daily question about floating point lack of precision.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9469345/3333

Comment: And it's time for the daily link to [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) too.

Comment: Thanks for the links! Totally missed the lack of precision of the floats.
Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its due to the limitation in the precision of float, try this

```
double tempd = 2451545 + 0.0009 + (77.048759/360) + 4682;
NSLog(@"tempd : %f", tempd);
```

Comment: That's it!!! Thanks for the quick response! 
2012-10-26 14:11:13.045 Sun Calculator[31166:c07] tempd : 2456227.214924

Comment: Please read the document I linked in the comment to your question, otherwise your next question will be about wrong calculation results of doubles ;-)